# A possible way to increase an inch in bicep/tricep for a Diabetic person

Tags: bodybuilding, mass

I was diagnosed with type 2 diabetics a year ago. For quite some time it was a shock to me. but with time I got over it. Now I have joined the gym. I want to increase the size on my biceps/ triceps /chest ... the problem is that a diabetic person has to control the calorie intake so that the blood sugar remains within safe limit. Now, if I can't eat much as needed does it mean there is no way i can get an increase in body mass. I'm currently 38 yrs old with 68kg.

please note that the diabetic is well controlled through diet only and I'm not on any medications or insulin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it's possible to grow muscle mass and have type-2 diabetes. (I have type-1 diabetes and am an endurance athlete who also does some strength and conditioning work at the gym.)

The main assumption I want to challenge is that you need the level of calorie restriction it sounds like you might have. Your carbohydrate intake will have a much, much larger impact on your blood sugar than protein (which has a very small effect) and fat. You should be able to fuel an active lifestyle with carbohydrates and include enough protein to build muscle. It might be worth talking to a dietician or nutritionist for some meal plans that will help with your goals.

Also, if diet and exercise alone aren't enough to keep your blood sugar where you want it to be **and** do the other things in life you want to accomplish, then consider adding insulin or an oral medication to your treatment plan. Obviously you should do this with a doctor's guidance, but there's no reason why you should restrict yourself to a therapy that limits you in some way.

Comment: a very encouraging reply I must say

Comment: Manther, Although it's a bit late but here's something I wanted to share so that readers may know. You were absolutely correct. I was able to gain 1 inch on my biceps from 14" to 15". so yes, with the correct diet and exercise things will work even if you are a diabetes. thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that!